# wait for ui data filter in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, icefaces

In a application many fields are there and all the fields are having filters ( text box) . so once user will enter the value in any one of filter immediately UI data (UI table) will start getting refreshed.

I wanted to wait for data to be loaded in UI and then apply the another filter.

Is there any way to wait until data gets loaded without using Thread.sleep

Answer (score 0):

Without further details provided by you, all I can recommend for now is [FluentWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html). For example:

```
final WebDriver driver = ...    
new FluentWait<>(driver).withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(1, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
    .until(
        webDvr -> !webDvr.findElements(By.xpath("//tr")).isEmpty()
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.... I have scenario like in page we have many filters and by default all data is getting display..... Now i wanted to apply filter one by one and before applying the second(next) filter wanted to wait for get data filter out for first(previous) filter. Also by default " //tr " is present with some data. Please help me out to resolve this as i am new to selenium world.

Answer (score 0):

I could able to perform this using below code -

```
public  boolean isElementDisplayed(WebElement element) {
    try{                
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

        return element.isDisplayed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
}


public  void loadingTimer(){
    String xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Loading...')]";
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));

    if (isElementDisplayed(element)) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver , 5);
        wait
           .until(ExpectedConditions
               .not(ExpectedConditions
                   .visibilityOf(element)));
    }
}
```